# помощь в разводке интернета по квартире

Tags: роутер

Добрый день, нужна помощь в техническом вопросе:

поровел интернет в квартире 100 Мбит, 
есть роутер WAN 100 Мбит, LAN 1Гбит

вход: кабель S-FTP 5Е
идет на компьютерную розетку и соединяется 4 контактами по типу В зеленый, зелено-белый, оранжевый, оренжево-белый

соединяется с роутером, интренет есть

нужно подключить ещё 1 компьютер через интренет розетку, а именно: из роутера выход на розетку1 обычным патчкордом, далее кабель до ведет к розетке2.
после подключения по схеме B и В на обеих розетках (подключал в так, как нарисовано на схеме) - интренета на компьютере 2 нет. подключение 8 контактов для поддержки внутренней сети 1 Гбит

Подскажите как правильно скоммутировать розетки (8 контактов), чтобы коннект с роутером был после прохождения такой схемы

1. роутер-выход(патчкорд)
2. розетка 1 (вход через патчкорд)
3. кабель (схема В)
4. розетка 2 (подключен кабель по схеме В)
5. патчкорд к комьютеру :)

Comment: Ну схемы вы вроде правильно написали, правда провода считаются слева-направо когда держите разъем ножами к себе и вверх. так что стандартная схема бел-ор, ор, бел-зел, син, бел-син, зел, бел-кор, кор. Боюсь так невозможно сказать почему не работает, возможно просто где то нет контакта, поврежден кабель в стене и т.п. вплоть до отсутствия драйверов на сетевуху и неправильных настроек роутера. Ставить комп вплотную к роутеру, через патчкорд, наладить так, потом переходить к подключению через кабель в стене. при проблемах очень жалательно наличие мультиметра

Comment: все получилось, перепроверил контакты, оранжевый был не полностью зафиксирован.